# Request nodeJS through a proxy. How to get the response header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, request

I'm trying to get the response header of a website and get the cookies that i can find inside. There is no problem, it's working when i start the request through a terminal with "node file.js".

But i'm launching the POST request through a local HTML page, so i used browersify for be able to launch a request from a client-side (or at least this is what i understood).

Then i'm using a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems. When i start the request from my local HTML page it's working and i can read the body but i'm not able to find the reponse header of the website and get the cookie that i need.

Here how my request looks like:

```
    function connectionInfoConcert(account, psw, next){
console.log("-------------CREATE HEADER-------------\n")
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://tranquil-thicket-71867.herokuapp.com/https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html',
    headers: {
      'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Language':'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
      'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
      'Connection':'keep-alive',
      'Content-Length':'184',
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'origin': 'https://www.infoconcert.com',
      'referer': 'https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html'
    },
    form: {
        origin:'',
        username: account,
        password: psw
    }
};
console.log("-------------END HEADER-------------\n-----------START REQUEST-----------------------")
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(body)
        console.log(response.headers['set-cookie'][0]); //obviously 'set-cookie' doesn't exist
    }
    else {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(response)
        console.log("-------------ERROR------------")
        return console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
});}
```

https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html is the website where i try to get the cookie

https://tranquil-thicket-71867.herokuapp.com is the CORS proxy that i'm using.

If some of you know how to be able to get the correct header it would be really nice !

Edit 1 :

The problem is when i do my request to "https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html" i can find the cookie that i'm looking for in response.headers["set-cookie"]. 
But because i'm doing the request from a html page it's not working and i'm doing the request to "https://tranquil-thicket-71867.herokuapp.com/https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html" but i can't find my cookie in the response.

Here the header of the response i got from "https://tranquil-thicket-71867.herokuapp.com/https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html"

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: server,vary,cache-control,content-type,content-encoding,p3p,date,expires,pragma,connection,x-cache-info,x-final-url,access-control-allow-origin
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 17:23:49 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
P3p: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR NID CUR ADM DEV OUR BUS"
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Cache-Info: not cacheable; response specified "Cache-Control: private"
X-Cors-Redirect-1: 302 https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/index.html
X-Cors-Redirect-2: 302 https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html
X-Final-Url: https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html
X-Request-Url: https://www.infoconcert.com/mon-infoconcert/connexion.html
```

So i think it's my proxy who doesn't forward the cookie that he gets.

If you need more details just ask.

Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: Looks fine to me, `response.headers["key"]` is generally the way to get at the headers K/V pairs...what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Also can you post the raw HTTP response you get when you send the POST request?

Comment: OK i edited, thanks for your help